# Puppeteer/Playwright is it possible to set the browser visible when launching as headless

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless, playwright, firefox-headless

Is it possible to launch Playwright with headless set to true and then later while the browser is still running change headless to false? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a particular test, as we configure at the start of the test, which cannot be modified as per my knowledge.