# Is there any possible way to hide and show browser via Playwright?

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I want to use this as setting for my app. Browser needs to be hidden or shown depending on checkbox value. I know that there is headless mode, but is there any way to this dynamically without instance recreating?

I thought that I could use an old instance which was shown for example, with old page data and new headless parameter but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related: [Puppeteer/Playwright is it possible to set the browser visible when launching as headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259683/puppeteer-playwright-is-it-possible-to-set-the-browser-visible-when-launching-as). Might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) since the browser runs on the server, so the client can't see it regardless of whether it's headless or not.

Comment: No you cant do this dynamically without creating a new instance.  Sorry. What you could do is save all the current cookies, reload the browser instance setting headless to true/false and then reload the cookies so you are back to where you originally was

Answer (score 0):

In the config file *Playwright.config.js* you use

`use: { headless: true, },`

here the same topic:
[How to run Playwright in headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611417/how-to-run-playwright-in-headless-mode)